# Why do we use 子ども to refer to a singular child (and 子供たち for plural)?

Tags: etymology

I was just thinking about how the term 子どもたち seems redundant since ども and たち are both plural markers. Of course you can use just 子 to refer to a child, but how did 子供 (and thus 子供たち) come to be the norm? Is the ども in 子供 unrelated etymologically?

I looked [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1016936830) for an answer which is what led to this confusion. I know that the kanji 供 doesn't refer to number, but this is written:

> 「こども」ということばは「こ」＋「ども」という組み合わせでできている。
>   「ども」は複数を表す接尾辞で「子ら」の「ら」や「子たち」の「たち」と同じ意味である。

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From 日本国語大辞典 (小学館, 2版)

> 元来は「子」の複数を表わす語だが、複数を表わすところから若年層の人々全般を指す用法を生じ、それが単数を表わす意味変化の契機となった。

Also...

> 院政末期には「こども達」という語形が見出され、中世、近世には「こども衆」という語を生じるなど、「大人に対する小児」の用法がいちだんと一般化し、同時に単数を表わすと思われる例が増える。

Comment: I guess that's more or less the predictable answer, huh. Interesting note on the evolution though.